# Connection between Squish IDE running on windows breaks with Squish Server running on Remote Embedded device now and then

Tags: squish

Connection between Squish Runner running on windows breaks with Squish Server running on Remote Embedded device now and then in between.

So the Squish server was build on embedded device using SDK version so that if there are any dependencies can be taken care.

Now when we run a script which is checking the UI on embedded device the connection breaks in between, not sure why is it happening

Is there a way to debug or identify who is breaking the connection.

Comment: Just to add both the Server and Runner are on same network

Comment: The reasons can be multiple.
Now, is there any row from the script executed before connection is lost, or the hooking to the AUT is not happening from starter?
I can try and help, but I think the fastest way is to ask for help from squish support team. You can try and read this before: https://kb.froglogic.com/display/KB/Collecting+Information+for+your+Support+Requests

Answer (score 0):

At first you should ensure that "Verbose Logging" is enabled for your squishserver performing the tests. (in the IDE go to: Menu->Edit->Preferences->Squish->Logging, and there enable (x)Verbose Logging. also enable everything under: Server Log Level)

Also ensure to use the "--verbose" option when starting squishserver and squishrunner from commandline.

Then look if there may any entries logged in the runner/server logs that could give some more advice about that what's gone wrong.